# Ruby 1.9.3 @OSX Lion and Cron

Tags: ruby, macos, command-line, cron

I installed Ruby 1.9.3p125 via this guide (up to point #5): [LINK](http://txcom2003.wordpress.com/2012/04/16/installing-ruby-on-rails-mysql-on-mac-os-x-10-7-lion/)

Now I have this problem: my script works wonderfully from my command line, but if I execute it from Cron it seems to use a default environment and defaults to /usr/bin/ruby instead of mine (~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby). What is the best way to have executed commands - manually or via cron - produce the same results?

PS: It seems to skip processing ~/.bash_login for example, where rvm is loaded into PATH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your crontab line, you can source the .bash_login before you script is run.

```
source ~/.bash_login && <your original command here>
```

That way your script will have everything you have when you run it.

Comment: Still nothing, won't load my gems :(

Answer (score 0):

The usual way recommended to do this would be to put the full path to the executable in your crontab. E.g.

crontab should show:

`/Users/Poochie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby /full/path/to/script.rb`

or whatever the full path is. It's much more robust than trying to get rvm loading, as here an rvm script is modifying your path for you. If you want to set it to whichever is the rvm default ruby (e.g. whatever was set by rvm use x.x.x --default), You can use: `/Users/Poochie/.rvm/bin/ruby` as the executable instead, e.g.:

`/Users/Poochie/.rvm/bin/ruby /full/path/to/script.rb`

Comment: I did that, but it won't pick my gems, it will search them in the system's ruby (1.8.7) and not mine (1.9.3)

Comment: this will probably require having the default set ruby by `rvm use 1.9.3 --default`. What's your output of `/Users/Poochie/.rvm/bin/ruby -e "puts RUBY_VERSION; puts $:.inspect"` (the latter `$:` is shorthand for ruby's load path)

Answer (score 0):

I actually found this post which helped me a lot: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545647/how-to-specify-rubygems-path-in-environment-less-ruby-script)

I managed to run my script as I wanted but the questions is theoretically still open because the issue could still affect cron usage in general.